# Strange difference accessing the numerical id of a user's facebook friends with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I've got a small problem. Using the Facebook graph for PHP, I access a user's info etc, from here

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
```

Now, accessing the id from there will give me the regular numerical id, which I store in my database.

However, when I access a user's friends

```
$facebook->api('/me/taggable_friends');
```

And then access their id, it gives me a whole different form of id meaning
I can't compare it to the ones in my database. Example: 
AaL4wTsOBmhG75qbHAWczJBaUZNlcxGr9C__pCEvgB1Y-oRPCpF2quaBw2oHrEU7-MKg3-5JYMNK_KR1C5rtz2r6Li1c65tfangz8JdLHIVt-w

What kind of id is this, where does it come from, and how can I reach the regular numerical id for the people in the friendlist?

Many thanks!

Comment: Taggable_friends are for tagging. Nothing else. And for tagging you want that token.

Comment: _“meaning I can't compare it to the ones in my database”_ – well, you’re not supposed to be able to do that.

Comment: I made the mistake Wizkid mentioned in using /taggable_friends instead of /friends, but using /friends it is posibble to compare the facebook id's of people